# BufferedReader running extremely slow

Tags: java, php, android, download, bufferedreader

I'm downloading an image from my web server like this:

```
conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
while ((resp = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    downloadedImage += resp;
}
```

However it's extremely slow. Downloading a single 500kb file takes about 15 seconds. Is there a better way to download the image?

Incase it matters: The file formatted as x lines, 80 UTF-8 chars each. Keeping the line breaks isn't important.

Thanks

Comment: My first guess would be that the weakest link here is the network / server, not the BufferedReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the weakest link here is the network / server, but anyway, you could improve performance of the `while` loop a little bit.

Using `+=` basically creates a new `StringBuilder` *each* time you invoke it. So `string1 += string2` is the same thing as invoking `string1 = new StringBuilder(string1).append(string2).toString();` Obviously, you would never do this in a loop that runns x times. So instead create *one* `StringBuilder` before you start the loop, and call `toString()` after finishing.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(downloadedImage);
while ((resp = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(resp);
}
downloadedImage = stringBuilder.toString();
```

If the loop doesn't run often, the performance improvement might not be as big, but since you're downloading an Image I suppose it runs quite a few times.

Comment: Hmm looks like youre correct about the host thing... I tried downloading the file through chrome and it takes about 10 seconds. Thanks for the StringBuilder tip as well, I wasn't aware that a new one was instatiated every time you concatenated!

Comment: @Nat glad to help. Also, a minor 'good practice' thing: If you didn't already and just cut that line off in your question,  you should close the `InputStream` after the loop.